# When accessing view,Using a tag faster than using a variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

which is faster ??

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

UIView *myView;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)myInit(){

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];

myView = view;

view.tag = 1;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad(){
[self myInit];

[self.view addSubview:myView];//accessing by variable

//OR

[self.view addSubView:[self.view viewWithTag:1];//accessing by tag

}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one you have a direct pointer access, in another you need to call a method, then find the indexed object and returning it to get the same object. I think you have your answer

Comment: Tag are very usefull, and i could not live without. There's lot of reason you can use tag, like in a nib file, and you don't want to polute your code by creating a special pointer for a view each time. If you have say, 50 views, that's a better approach to tag them... You should not focus on performance when performance is not needed, obj-c is really not a performance oriented language, even if it seems fast. You should really focus on design and flexibility when you code on obj-c.

Comment: I should really focus on design and flexibility when you code on obj-c .Good advice to me.thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to retrieve elements using "`viewWithTag`" if the elements were hooked to the cell programmatically (i.e. not defined in a NIB and hooked-up via IBOutlets)—this prevents multiple labels etc. to be created for each instance of the cell.Definitely using a variable and /or IBOUtlet in NIBS has the upper merit more ever because when we want to fetch a view via `viewWithTag` ,the compiler runs a `for` loop within its subViews and fetch the first view it finds with the given tag.Hence in case where you have two view with same tag ,using `viewWithTag` always have a major disadvantage.

Comment: thank you for explaining a advantage and disadvantage of using tag :)